# I want to calculate profit loss percentage over n days. But getting this KeyError : 0. How to solve this?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
def ProfitLoss(nDays):
    days = data.tail(nDays)
    prft_loss =  (( days['Open Price'] - days['Close Price'] ) / days['Close Price'])


    print (prft_loss)


    for i in range(nDays):

        if prft_loss[i] > 0:
            print('Profit : ', prft_loss[i]*100, '%')
        else:
            print('Loss : ', prft_loss[i]*100, '%') 


ProfitLoss(2)

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Unless you share some of your data it may be very difficult to help you.

Comment: please share input data

Comment: I'm passing no. of days in function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ProfitLoss(nDays):
    days = data.tail(nDays)
    prft_loss =  (( days['Open Price'] - days['Close Price'] ) / days['Close Price'])

    prft_loss = pd.DataFrame({ 'pl': prft_loss.values})


    for i,j in prft_loss.iterrows():

        if (j<0).bool():

            print('Loss',j.values*100,'%') 
        else:
            print('Profit : ',j.values*100,'%')
```